# Can this Rosser-like trick also work as a proof of the first incompleteness theorem?

Tags: lo.logic

The context of this question is related to proving the first incompleteness by alternative ways related to Rosser's trick. So, for a proof by negation, we assume that $T$ is complete, and fulfills Gödel's criteria of effectively capturing all computable functions, etc..

Can $T$ decide on sentence $\sigma$ defined below?

$\sigma \iff \\\forall k (\operatorname {Proof}_T(k, \ulcorner \sigma \urcorner) \to \\\forall s: \exists x [\operatorname {Proof}_T(x,\ulcorner s \urcorner) \land   x \leq k] \lor \exists y [\operatorname {Proof}_T(y, \operatorname {neg} (\ulcorner s\urcorner)) \land y \leq k])$

In English this reads as: This sentence is only provable at lengths such that every sentence is either provable or disprovable below (non-strictly) it.

The idea is that, as defined, $\sigma$ can only be provable by proofs having non-standard Gödel codes, meaning that if $T$ is complete then $\sigma$ must be false, i.e. we have $T \vdash \neg \sigma$.

So, if we assume $T$ to be complete, then this criterion, I think, would separate standard from non-standards, so if a code of a proof doesn't fulfill that feature, i.e. not every sentence is decidable below it, then this code is standard!

However, I'm not sure of this later feature, that's why I'm not sure of the decidability of $\neg \sigma$ in $T$.

Of course this can be settled brutally by defining a minimal for such proofs, i.e. for example define:

${\frak K} = \min k :  \forall s \, (\exists x [\operatorname {Proof}_T(x,\ulcorner s \urcorner) \land   x \leq k] \lor \exists y [\operatorname {Proof}_T(y, \operatorname {neg} (\ulcorner s\urcorner)) \land y \leq k])$

Then define the diagonal $\pi$ as:

$\pi \iff \forall x (\operatorname {Proof}_T(x,\ulcorner \pi \urcorner) \to x \geq {\frak K})$

And clearly $\pi$ would be undecidable in $T$.

> What is the status of $\sigma $ in $T$ should we assume that $T$ is complete and fulfill Gödel's criteria.

Comment: There can be no expressible feature that separates standard from nonstandard numbers, since this would violate induction.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, Yes. Of course, that's the argument really. The idea is that if we assume that $T$ fulfill Gödel's criteria, then we can show that completeness of $T$ would lead to $T$ expressing standard-ness in its language, and this cannot be as you said, so this mean that it cannot be complete, thus proving the first incompleteness theorem. The proof above actually demonstrates that $\pi$ violates completeness, and I think $\sigma$ as well.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I need also to note that I'm not sure if this proof demands induction for it to go through? It may work (if it can) even in absence of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two major issues with the proposal.

First, if $\sigma$ is refutable, then in the standard model the biconditional will be vacuously true, since there will be no $k$ for which $\text{Proof}_T(k,\ulcorner\sigma\urcorner)$. This seems to trivialize the idea.

But second, even if one were to fix that somehow, the more serious point is that PA proves that there can be no number $k$ that serves as a bound for the size of a code of a proof of every sentence $s$ or its negation. The reason is that any proof a sentence must mention that sentence, and from this it follows (using any of the standard proof predicates) that the code of any proof will be at least as great as the code of the sentence being proved. Because you are asking for $k$ to have the property that it bounds the proofs of every sentence or its negation, this is impossible — there can be no number $k$ with the property mentioned on the RHS of your biconditional.

From this point of view, any $\sigma$ that fulfills the biconditional will itself have to be refutable.

Comment: But this is strange, if $T$ is complete then it must decide on *every* sentence in its language, and it must do that in standard length (i.e. the code of the proof must be standard) no matter how big that sentence is. So, if there is a non-standard, then it would be bigger than all standards, and so the decision of $T$ must be completed before any non-standard number.

Comment: I didn't get the first issue, what do you mean by vacuously true?

Comment: You are evidently thinking only of standard sentences when you say that, but the quantifier $\forall s$ will necessarily include nonstandard $s$.

Comment: For the first issue, if $\sigma$ is refutable, then the implication (if k is a proof of $\sigma$, then ....) is vacuous, since there will be no such $k$.

Comment: There would be no such implication when you refute $\sigma$, this would turn into conjunction with the refutation of the consequent.

Comment: The point is:  if $\sigma$ is not provable, then $\forall k (\text{Proof}(k,\sigma)\to\cdots)$ is trivially true.

Comment: That's not how it goes. We say that if $T \vdash \neg \sigma$ then what is on the right of the biconditional must also be negated. Note, that $T \vdash \neg \sigma$ doesn't mean that there is no proof of $\sigma$, there can still be a proof but non-standardly coded.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $s$ is standard or not. If $T$ is complete then it must prove it or its negation in STANDARD length. Because that's what we mean by complete.

Comment: I am saying that any non-provable $\sigma$ trivially fulfills your biconditional. Your biconditional simply does not say what you think it is says.

Comment: Your remark about standardness is wrong, since T being complete is an assumption in the metatheory, which refers only to standard sentences.

Comment: Ah! I see now what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the triviality of $\sigma$ is unprovable, then yes that is true, same matter occurs with Rosser's actually, this is not a point against this method. I need actually to address the second point.

Comment: You have asked a number of questions on this theme recently here on MO. But because they have often exhibited what seem to me to be basic misunderstandings of the subject, I would urge you to consider asking on math.stackexchange.com instead of MO. You will get plenty of attention there.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Thanks.

Comment: See [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748706/can-this-serve-as-an-alternative-proof-of-g%c3%b6dels-first-incompleteness-theorem)